# Python string extraction and stripping

Tags: python, string, split

I have this string - `E1(05): 12 13 16 18 24 E2(01):13` - and all i wish back is:

- the contents after the `E1` i.e `05`,
- the list of the 5 numbers i.e. `06 08 12 18 29`,
- the contents after the `E2` i.e. `01`,
- and lastly, the last number i.e. `13`.

I have tried the 're' function but it returns hex string and cannot find examples to strip/split this out with success. There MUST be an elegant way of solving this.

Comment: from this example, what i understand is , you just need all numbers from string, right ?

Comment: *"...the list of the 5 numbers i.e. 06 08 12 18 29"* Where did you get these numbers from?

Comment: what should be matched from this `E1(05): 12 13 16 18 24 E2(01):13` input: `[05, 01]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `re.findall()` by using word boundaries around `\d+` (in order to not match 1 in E1, etc):

```
In [9]: s = "E1(05): 12 13 16 18 24 E2(01):13"

In [10]: re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', s)
Out[10]: ['05', '12', '13', '16', '18', '24', '01', '13']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```
data = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b','YOUR_STRING')
ans = [int(i) for i in data]
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This doesn't work. `ans` is `[1, 5, 12, 13, 16, 18, 24, 2, 1, 13]`

Comment: You just need \b to filterout those E1 stuff. Sorry i didn't recognize at first

Comment: Right, but now your answer is essentially a duplicate of Kasramvd's. The only difference is that you explicitly convert the matches to integers, and it's unclear if that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to get the id of that `E` token and the information after that, here's a simple solution:

```
import re

data = "   E1(05): 12 13 16 18 24 E2(01):13 "

for v in data.split("E"):
    if v.strip() == '':
        continue

    m = re.match(r'E.*?\((.*?)\):(.*)', 'E' + v)
    e_id, e_data = m.group(1), [int(v) for v in m.group(2).split()]
    print(e_id, e_data)
```

Then you'd get something like this:

```
('05', [12, 13, 16, 18, 24])
('01', [13])
```